# Fourier transform of partial derivative

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am currently doing some reading on using Fourier transforms to solve PDEs and I stumbled upon a property that I am not sure how to prove.

Suppose we have a heat-equation $u_t(x,t)=\alpha^2 u_{xx}(x,t)$ with $(x,t)\in \mathbb R\times [0,\infty)$. Now we can use a Fourier transform in regards to $x$, which yields

$$\mathcal F(\alpha^2 u_{xx})=-\alpha^2 \xi^2 \mathcal F(u)$$

This is obvious. But now my textbook says that

$$\mathcal F(u_t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u e^{-ix\xi}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^\infty ue^{-ix\xi}dx = \frac{d}{dt}\mathcal F(u)$$
and I am not really sure why this holds.

I think I have read a theorem, a long time ago, that said something about changing the order of integrals and derivatives by using Lebesgue's theorem. Is this the way to go? Or is there an easier way to argue why the above holds?

Comment: This is indeed the way to go.

Comment: [Wikipedia has a page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) on this. Are you looking for a proof, or some kind of intuitive argument, or something else?

Comment: @DavidZ well yes and no. I'll check out the wikipedia page, but I am basically just looking for an idea on how to proof it and not really the proof in every detail (although I'd read that, too, if I found it).